# Programmatically view IL

Tags: c#, .net-core

Is there a way that I can view the IL code of some types inside an assembly? I know I can view the IL using Linqpad or Reflector but that is an out of process thing. Can I do it in code and get something like a string back that contains a method's IL?

E.g

```
var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"c:\mycode.dll");
var type = asm.GetType("Namespace.Classname");
var il = type.GetIl();
```

Comment: https://github.com/jbevain/cecil

Comment: @SLaks I would prefer the more official https://github.com/mono/cecil instead.

Comment: @omajid: That's just a fork.

Answer (score -1):

While you can't extract the whole IL of a type, you can have access of the IL of each method via MethodBase.GetMethodBody().

You can combine Metadata extraction via reflection and the method body to perform your analysis.

Keep on mind that you are returned the raw IL steam along with labels and exception sections, and you are responsible for the mixup.

Comment: It would be helpful to me, to understand why an answer is not useful, otherwise I cannot make any improvements. Why the downvote?